# Specifying layer and BBOX in URL when opening GeoExplorer?

Tags: geoexplorer, url

I would like to specify the state that the GeoExplorer map window and which layers are turned on when opening it up by a URL.

I have started to go through the code but I feel this must be quite a common user requirement.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current map config (it's a tool in the composer), and you will get a permalink url back which will reopen the exact same map (extent, layers). The JSON config will be stored in a sqlite database.

For example:

geoexplorer/composer/#maps/1